# How float with 'e' will work in a variable declaration

Tags: java, scjp

```
public class TypeConversion3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float f = 12e-1F;
        final long l = 12L;
        f = f + l;
        System.out.println(f); //prints 13.2
    }
}
```

No idea how it prints the value 13.2. I some where read that e is 2.718 but what is this `float f = 12e-1F;` representing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "e" is not the natural logarithm base, but short for "exponent". The number following the "e" is a power of ten, so 12e-1F is 1.2.

Answer (score 3):

12e-1 is [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) and means `12 * 10^-1` which is 1.2

Answer (score 2):

The e stands for 10^, or power of 10.

12E-1F = 12.0 * 10 ^ -1 = 12.0 / 10 = 1.2

It is part of the syntax as defined in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2).

The Base for a Natural Logarithm (e) is available as [`Math.E`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#E) (Eulers Number), or to use it as the base for an exponent, simple use [`Math.exp(-1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#exp-double-). Note however that parameters and result types are `double` not `float`.

Comment: so -1 is the power in this case ?

Comment: 10 raised to the power of (-1) yes.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing [E notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) with [Euler's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) which is approx 2.71828.

Java number literals use `e` as E notation thus
`e` in `12e-1F` means `float number 12*10^-1` which is `1.2`.